# cassandra queries with order by on clustering key

Tags: cassandra

I currently have a table that looks like

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
   id bigint,
   data_source text,
   timestamp timestamp,
   latitude double,
   longitude double,
   PRIMARY KEY ((id, data_source), timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)
```

I am trying to get the last location on that entity so my query looks like this

`SELECT FROM locations WHERE id = {} AND data_source = {} ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1`

Intuitively, I would expect this query to perform equivalently to the absent of the `ORDER BY` clause, but I'm not sure if that is correct. Can I assume this is correct?

The documentation at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refClstrOrdr.html seems to suggest otherwise. 
`You can order query results to make use of the on-disk sorting of columns. You can order results in ascending or descending order. The ascending order will be more efficient than descending. If you need results in descending order, you can specify a clustering order to store columns on disk in the reverse order of the default. Descending queries will then be faster than ascending ones.`

This table is expected to grow very quickly within the next couple of months. Do I need to create a new table with the clustering order by clause reversed to prevent any performance issue in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, I am assuming you are putting values in id and data_source, because you can't order by without specifying partition key.

Now, your query can give same result as without Order By or may not, if multiple timestamp are present.
Because look at your table creation, default order of timestamp is ASC, so if you fire same query without order by you will get row with lowest timestamp.
With order by you will get row with highest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You get the best performance when the query `ORDER BY` matches the table's `CLUSTERING ORDER BY`.

So if your query pattern is to access the highest timestamp, then you definitely need to store your data in a table with `CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC)`.

When a query sort order does not match the on-disk order, then data will be fetched from disk in a less efficient manner and sorted in-memory, and your queries will be much slower (which is why this is considered an anti-pattern).